# shorthand in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery codes:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#masthead ul li").mouseover(function(){
    $("#masthead ul li").removeClass("cr");
    $(this).toggleClass("cr");
});
   }); 

  $(document).ready(function() {
$("#intUl li").mouseover(function(){
    $("#intUl li").removeClass("cr");
    $(this).toggleClass("cr");
});
});
```

Can we write shorthand for two similar jquery code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey jasmine, looks like you've been on here for 2 months and haven't accepted an answer yet! Might want to go do that for a few of your questions, people will want to help you a lot more if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#masthead ul li, #intUl li").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("cr");
        $(this).toggleClass("cr");
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#masthead ul li, #intUL li').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("cr");
    $(this).toggleClass("cr");  
});
```

Does the same as the original code; <strike>not sure why you're removing a class only to readd it, however. If you're trying to get it to flash or something, I'm fairly sure it won't work as you're expecting.</strike>

Misunderstood original intent; a commenter clarified for me, and I fixed it :)

Comment: That won't actually do what he's trying to achieve. You're removing the cr class from the same element you mousedover and then toggle it. He wants to remove it from all the siblings first and then add it to the moused over. So only one LI will have 'cr' at a time.

Comment: @Parrots I'd missed that, well played

Comment: toggleClass should be addClass since removeClass won't apply to the source element unless you do .siblings().andSelf()?

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggleCRClass(event) {
    $(event.target).siblings().removeClass('cr');
    $(event.target).addClass('cr');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#masthead ul li, #intUl li").mouseover(toggleCRClass);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#masthead ul li, #intUL li').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('cr').siblings().removeClass('cr');
});
```